# How to merge 2 Array with loop position

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays :

```
$arr1 = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7');
$arr2 = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
```

I want to loop `$arr2` into `$arr1` but if the length of `$arr1` is less than the algorithm requires, only use as many elements of `$arr2` as necessary.

I want to achieve this result:

```
$arr2 = array('1', '2', '3', 'a', '4', '5', '6', 'b', '7');
```

I have already tried :

```
$count = ceil(count($arr1) / 3) - 1;
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    array_splice($arr1, 3, 0, $arr2);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you need make the splice point `($i+1)*3`, and only splice in the `$arr2[$i]` value, not the entire array. Also you need to work backwards from the end as inserting values into the array causes the indexes to change.

```
$arr1 = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7');
$arr2 = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
$count = ceil(count($arr1) / 3) - 1;
for ($i = $count - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    array_splice($arr1, ($i + 1) * 3, 0, $arr2[$i]);
}
print_r($arr1);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => a
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
    [7] => b
    [8] => 7
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/bGJPq)

Note that dependent on the result you want to achieve when `$arr1` is a multiple of 3 elements, you may want to change

```
$count = ceil(count($arr1) / 3) - 1;
```

to

```
$count = ceil((count($arr1) + 1) / 3) - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just insert element of `$arr2` ervey 3 element2 of `$arr1`, [Demo](https://3v4l.org/lMt0G)

```
$result = [];
foreach($arr1 as $key => $value){
    $result[] = $value;
    if((0 == ($key + 1) % 3) && isset($arr2[($key + 1)/3-1])){
        $result[] = $arr2[($key + 1)/3-1];
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: It prints `a` twice.  You probably mean `$result[] = $arr2[intval(($key + 1) / 3) - 1];`

Answer (score 0):

At every third index, splice in a member of your other array.  Note the original array changes in size, so we need to adjust inserted key accordingly upon each splice.

```
<?php
for($i=3, $s=0, $c=count($arr1); $i<$c; $i+=3, $s++) {
    array_splice($arr1, $i+$s, 0, $arr2[$s]);
}
var_export($arr1);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '1',
  1 => '2',
  2 => '3',
  3 => 'a',
  4 => '4',
  5 => '5',
  6 => '6',
  7 => 'b',
  8 => '7',
)
```

Same omitting the statement of the loop

```
for(
    $i=3, $s=0, $c=count($arr1);
    $i<$c;
    array_splice($arr1, $i+$s, 0, $arr2[$s++]), $i+=3
);
```

Comment: Start at index 3, to bypass the if.